# How to call event for command button in the grid

Tags: jquery

I have various command buttons in my Grid such as 'Insert', 'Update', etc.... I customize the Grid adding the buttons manually and placing ID's like btnInsert, btnUpdate, and so on. The buttons are shown when I click the 'Insert' or 'Update' image.

My issue is: How can I directly call the event handler for the above buttons? I just want to validate the inputs before the data is saved to the DB. Since the buttons are inside the Grid, I am finding it difficult to call the button's event handler. It would be nice to know of any ways this is possible.

I used the below code:

```
$('#btnUpdate').click(function(e)s {
        alert('checking the fun');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I also used the Update button's client ID:

```
$('#RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl05_btnUpdate').click(function(e){
 //Input validation
});
```

-Thanks

Comment: Just make sure you no which class to use...
# = ID
. = Class
Etc. so make sure that's ok with your code, else the event catcher won't work

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the jquery documentation page about events:
http://docs.jquery.com/Events

You could use one of these with something like: butonname.onclick( function() {
  //your validation here
});

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$('#btnInsert').click();
```

However, this is not the best style. The validation function shoud be a function of its own, then you can call it from the button event handler and other places alike.

Comment: I used the above related code already but no use it is not getting called.

Comment: There is a difference between click() (note: no arguments), which triggers a click event on the element in question, and click(function) with a function argument, that **binds** the function to the click event of the element. You might say: In the first case, something happens immediately, in the latter case, a function is registered for later execution. You have to be clear which one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some of the HTML for the grid? That  would really help us be able to help you.

My guess is that you will want to give all the update buttons a CLASS like btn-update.  Then you can use javascript like this:

```
$(".btn-update").bind('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $btn = event.currentTarget; //$btn will be a jQuery object containing the button that was clicked
  //call validate function
  //send data to server
});
```